# TemporalDate from DateTime - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify for my project and trying to save the selected date from datepicker to the model.

DatePicker is giving the date in DateTime object, when i try to convert it to TemporalDate its giving me a day before date. i.e if i select todays date and assigning it to the TemporalDate then i am getting yesterday's date.

Here is my code :

```
var d1 = TemporalDate(pickedDate);
var d4 = TemporalDate(pickedDate.toUtc());
var d2 = TemporalDate(pickedDate.toLocal());
var d3 = TemporalDate(pickedDate).getDateTime();
```

pickedDate is holding today's date but the d1,d2,d3,d4 all is having yesterday's date.

Expected result is to get the today's date in the TemporalDate variable.

Comment: Did you check your pickedDate is correct?

Comment: Im having this problem too... any luck?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the date. It is showing a day before because it is on the universal date. So you just need to convert the universal date to local date.

```
var dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(selectedDate.toString(), true);
var dateLocal = dateTime.toLocal();
```

Answer (score 1):

After a long research on the date and temporal date I learned to handle the dates as expected.

In general, picked date is in your local timezone based date. You know that the timezone is the key here. each timezone is shows different time. but the UTC is the universal time. which means the UTC is a common time for entire globe.

Thats the reason, aws is created TemporalDateTime. Whenever we create temporal date, the local dateTime is converted into UTC. whoever is wants the date in their timezone then you can convert it to your timezone. for eg. IST 6am is 7.30 PM of a day before for EST timezone. which means they are 10h 30 mins before IST.

Hope this helps someone to understand the date times.

Answer (score 0):

This Code Work For Me, Earlier don't know why my date is not correct if I used the UTC timezone method.

so this code saved my night because I already wasted my day.
It Works For AWS timestamp

```
    String dateTimeFormatter(String dateTime, {String? format}) {
  var newDate = DateFormat(format ?? "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
      .format(DateTime.parse(dateTime));

  print(newDate);
  return newDate;
}
```